# How do I insert strings into many lines of code? (Not refactor)

Tags: excel, command-line, automation, dry, superuser

I'll give an example here.  I want to insert code from a separate file into an many elements of another file.

This is for DRY to hundreds of lines of code.  Is there a loop or something that can do it via super user/command line?  What if file 1 was in CSV format or on google sheets/excel?

This is different than refactoring because when you refactor, the same information is spread throughout the code.  For this example, it's different values.

The application I'm looking for had to do with youtube data-ids.  I tried to make the example generic so that the solution can be applied robustly.

File 1:

```
s
st
str
stri
kdjslf
fdslf
fdsfk
jklijo
gritro
fehfkjj
```

File 2:

```
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
str = "";
```

File 3 is what I want to happen but for hundreds of lines of code:

File 3:

```
str = "s";
str = "st";
str = "str";
str = "stri";
str = "kdjslf";
str = "fdslf";
str = "fdsfk";
str = "jklijo";
str = "gritro";
str = "fehfkjj";
```

I've looked all over google and can't find this solution.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you copy you data from File 1 into Excel into column A, you can add a formula in B1 of:    ="str="""&A1&""";"

Then just copy it down the column

Comment: Why are there three quotes after the second equals sign on each side of &A1&?  Also, why is there a quotation before str?  I know how to make columns and understand the A and B column but I'm confused on how the formula works.

Comment: the formula says to take the string literal {str="} (I will use parentheses to denote the literal value for now.  You would not use the parentheses in Excel) and concatenate the value of cell A1 and concatenate the string literal {";}.  So our pseudo Excel formula would look like {str="}+A1+{";}

Comment: Excel doesnt use parentheses to denote a string literal; it uses quotes.  To Excel, a string literal is started with a quote and ended with a quote.  If you want to have a quote as part of your string, you have to use 2 quotes right next to each other so that Excel will understand that you are not ending the string.

Comment: Try taking the formula and play around with it by adding spaces or other characters in between the quote marks to see what happens.

Comment: I played around with it a bit and it works.  Thanks grambo!